# Native vs Immigrant plants

Tags: botany, ecology

**Is this statement applicable to any known plant/region combinations?**

> Plant species X, Y, and Z are truly indigenous to region R. Other "immigrant" species can be destroyed by drought or harsh weather, but these species will always be part of the region R.

(all species in question are "benign" - like wheat; please disregard climate change and other global disasters like nuclear wars).

PS. Background: I heard this statement (with specific X,Y,Z,R) attributed to a "leading botanist" (probably 20th century), but I don't really see how this can be true (my biology education ended in high school though; I am a mathematician by training).

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: @Chris: "Is this statement applicable to any known plant/region combinations"?

Comment: @sds You should probably edit the question to put that directly in the question itself. Also, this seems to assume the foreign plant comes from a region significantly different from R and can't kill off the native plants before bad weather kills off the foreigner. Also assumes native plants will always be able to survive extreme conditions in the region, but with climate change, the region could change beyond what native plants can handle.

Comment: @user137: this phrase is the _first line_ of the question!

Comment: @sds Sorry, I must not have seen it, I think I was looking for a question mark.

Comment: Yes definitely, within sufficiently loose defintions of "indigenous", "immigrant" and "always", and time frame that is not too long. Isn't you questions basically "*Is this statement patently false?*" (too which I would respond "No").

Comment: @fileunderwater: so, as usual, "if you misspell `milk` 4 times, you can end up with `beer`". Right?